How can I start recording a video with as few actions as possible on my iPhone?
While that might sound like an easy question to answer, unfortunately it's not.
I have an iPhone 6s running iOS 15.8.2. The most obvious thing to do is with the screen locked, swipe left and start recording. Only problem: camera app has a bad habit of remembering the last selection and that does not help to quickly start recording. And no, the setting to not remember the last action is ineffective. Unfortunately.
Next thing I tried was to voice activate it. But that was too far fetched, the microphone was always on, it was draining the battery and I wasn't even close to achieving what I wanted so I gave up.
Then I came to the closest solution possible: shortcuts. I created a shortcut that starts exactly that action (take video with back camera, begin recording immediately) and then saves the video to the gallery. "Awesome!" I thought. Now I only have to find a way to activate it from the lock screen. That was simple, I added it to the widgets so now I need 3 moves after the lock screen appears: swipe left, tap on the shortcut and unlock the phone. Only to my great disappointment I realized that this isn't flawless: if I tap on the shortcut and I'm not quick enough to place my finger on the fingerprint sensor before the touch id prompt appears, then the action is canceled quite quickly. This is somehow quirky.
My question is if there is a more straightforward way to start recording a video with as few actions as possible or if the current solution could be streamlined.

Make sure there is a camera icon in the Control Center.
If so, swipe up, hold on the icon, and swipe your finger to "Record Video".
If not, go to Settings > Control Center > and find the camera icon.
